# Border wont apply programatically to my grid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, border, styling

I have problems with Styling my grid, I am working on small app for caffe bars lets say, customer is able to choose drink from the middle of screen and drink will be shown in the right part of screen in my grid, this is how that looks like right now (when customer choose something - lets say Coke, sprite etc.):

[image]

This is my code for now :

```
public DrinksPanel(byte[] image)
        : base()
    {
        BrushConverter MyBrush8 = new BrushConverter();
        var myBorder = new Border();
        myBorder.Background = (Brush)MyBrush8.ConvertFrom("#83D744");

        Thickness marginT = this.Margin;
        marginT.Top = 10;
        this.Margin = marginT;


        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        col1.Width = new GridLength(45);

        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        col2.Width = new GridLength(80, GridUnitType.Star);

        ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        col3.Width = new GridLength(45);

        this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
        this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);



        this.Height = 45;
        this.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        this.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;


        ArticleNameLabel.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        ArticleNameLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        ArticleNameLabel.FontSize = fontSize;

        ArticleNameLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;

        ArticleNameLabel.FontFamily = Util.Font;//new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf#Helvetica Neue LT Std");
        ArticleNameLabel.Content = tekst;
        ArticleNameLabel.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        ArticleNameLabel.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 1);

        ArticleNameLabel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        ArticleNameLabel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);
        ArticleNameLabel.Width = Double.NaN;
        ArticleNameLabel.Height = Double.NaN;


        QuantityNumberLabel.Width = Double.NaN;
        QuantityNumberLabel.Height = Double.NaN;

        QuantityNumberLabel.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        QuantityNumberLabel.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
        QuantityNumberLabel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
        ArticleNameLabel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);

        QuantityNumberLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        QuantityNumberLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        QuantityNumberLabel.FontFamily = Util.Font;
        QuantityNumberLabel.FontSize = numberSize;
        QuantityNumberLabel.Content = "x1";
        QuantityNumberLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        BrushConverter MyBrush3 = new BrushConverter();

        QuantityNumberLabel.Background = (Brush)MyBrush3.ConvertFrom("#83D744");




        _image.Width = Double.NaN;
        _image.Height = Double.NaN;

        _image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        _image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        _image.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        _image.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 1);

        _image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        _image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);

        Image.Source = GetSlikaFromByte(image);

        Rectangle background = new Rectangle();
        background.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        background.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
        background.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        background.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty,3);

        background.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        background.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        background.Width = Double.NaN;
        background.Height = Double.NaN;
        background.Fill = (Brush)MyBrush.ConvertFrom("#50000000");

        _animation = new DoubleAnimation(numberSize, numberSize + 15, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300)));

        _animation.AutoReverse = true;



        this.Children.Add(background);
        this.Children.Add(_image);
        this.Children.Add(ArticleNameLabel);
        this.Children.Add(QuantityNumberLabel); 
    }
```

***So my question is guys, how could apply

> myborder

around grid?***

**If anyone could help me about this I would appreciate that so much =)**

Comment: In WPF, you **don't** write _code_ for creating an user interface, but you **do** create a XAML markup where you define your view.

Comment: @dymanoid well in this case I needed to recognize when user choose article so Im creating new grid in the part of my app, so on I need to add border also by code :\

Comment: Please read more about WPF: such topics as MVVM, styling, triggers, and commands. Using these tools, you will create stunning user interfaces in XAML and ensure correct business logic in code.